# Mariadb 10.3 on debian segfaults

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, debian, innodb

Somehow my mariadb-server crashed. Since then it just segfaults. I tried innodb_force_recovery all the way up to 6, nothing changed. The errorlog is really not helpful. Any idea what i could try?
Im using Debian 10 with mariadb 10.3.27-0+deb10u1

```
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Disabling background log and ibuf IO write threads.
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-05-07 16:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery=6 skips redo log apply
210507 16:06:12 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
...

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x49000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x55c56d01491e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x54d)[0x55c56cb432ed]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12730)[0x7f4186447730]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x980aba)[0x55c56cd23aba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa4d668)[0x55c56cdf0668]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa525ca)[0x55c56cdf55ca]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa52644)[0x55c56cdf5644]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xaa1db2)[0x55c56ce44db2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xaa2cba)[0x55c56ce45cba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa86491)[0x55c56ce29491]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4ddaf3)[0x55c56c880af3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9111e4)[0x55c56ccb41e4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x68)[0x55c56cb459d8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5dbf69)[0x55c56c97ef69]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x98a)[0x55c56c9800ea]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x51cb55)[0x55c56c8bfb55]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x3f9)[0x55c56c8c67c9]
csu/libc-start.c:342(__libc_start_main)[0x7f41859f109b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x2a)[0x55c56c8b9c8a]
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
...
```

This is my my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
general_log=1
innodb_force_recovery = 6
log_warnings=6
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/general.log
innodb_file_per_table=1
character_set_server = utf8mb4
```

EDIT: I reinstalled mariadb using apt, deleted any config except the my.cnf before that. Changed nothing. When i copy the datadir to a fresh install with just mariadb, mariadb segfaults on the new machine too.

Comment: What is the minor version number? ... 10.3.?

Comment: mariadb-server-10.3                  1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1
mariadb-server-core-10.3             1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1